# How to log line number of the part of code that was executed using VS 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, logging, numbers, line

I have huge code which has a bug and I have no knowledge of the code. The only thing I know is that when a particular input field is giiven a +ve value it generates correct output and is a -ve value is given an invalid output is generated. From the analysis of the output it was concluded that the issue could be due to improper initialization of a variable (garbage value). I believe the fastest way to resolve the issue would be the analysis of the variables present in the uncommon code of the two executions(success and failure). **What I need now is a way to log the file name and line number of the code that was executed, in proper sequence**.  I'll be able to compare both the log files and determine the section of code that might have the bug. The **code is in C** and **VS2010** is the available tool.

Thanks & Regards
 - Mustafa

Comment: What is wrong with `Console.WriteLine` in the files that you think are causing the problems?

Comment: @Danny Perhaps that it's not a C function, right?

Comment: @H2CO3 Wow. Really misread that question. I feel  stupid now :(

Comment: Thank you guys for the replies. I think using trace points as suggested by Soundararajan with right set of commands will help me achieve what I want.

Answer (score 2):

While line and file are good:

`__LINE__` - The line number

`__FILE__` - The current file

The currently executing function is also **very** helpful:

`__FUNCTION__` - The name of the current function

Answer (score 1):

There are some [predefined macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that will help you out here like `__FILE__` or `__LINE__`

Answer (score 0):

Use the tracepoint feature of Visual studio. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/232dxah7(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: I believe i can use the tracepoints to achieve what i want. Have a trace point at every line in the code and make it print whatever that is required.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your time and replies. Really appreciate it. Kindly let me know if there is a better solution.